# Java log4j not working

Tags: java, log4j

I want to use log4j for generating the logs.
For this I am using the following code :

```
package com.idm.Test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class log4jExample {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Hello this is a debug message 1");
        log.info("Hello this is a debug message 2");
        log.info("Hello this is a debug message 3");
    }
}
```

My log4j properties file is given below :

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log=G:\\logs
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}\\log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I want to generate log file inside

```
G:\logs\log.out
```

But the problem is that when I run this. There is no log file is created on this path.
When I already created one file into that location with log.out name and run again it is not showing me the logs inside this file.

**I put my log4j.properties file inside com.idm.Test package.**

Comment: Notice that you did not define a level for the logger

Comment: @Asettouf Should I have to defined it into properties file?

Comment: @Asettouf My file path is correct or I have to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the the Java Util Logger in your code

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

this is not the log4j logger. Fix your import and ensure that your configuration file will be found (either put in on the classpath or specifiy the location with the `log4j.configuration` system property - see [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit))

Note: OP edited question and uses the right import now...

---

By the way do not use log4j (1) anymore. It has reached its [EOL](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces) and is not  [Java 9 ready](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/moving_on_to_log4j_2).

Go with [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) (or other current logging frameworks) instead.

Comment: When I am using `import org.apache.log4j.Logger` there is same issue. this is not created any file on path location and if I already created one file on location it is not adding the logs here.

Comment: Have a look at the [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) and how log4j1 tries to find the configuration file. But really do not invest any time on log4j1 if you start to use logging (except you have to deal with legacy code)

Comment: Showing me on console `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.idm.log4jExample).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
`

Comment: Use `-Dlog4j.debug` during start to enable log4j internal logging and check if your configuration file was found (see [Example 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_under_Tomcatc) here).

Comment: Do you have a Maven project?

Comment: I have Java Project using Eclipse.

Comment: Ensure that your log4j.properties file is on the classpath root. Placing it inside a package will not work. Even better specifiy the location with the `log4j.configuration` system property.

Answer (score 1):

I did same like your code and properity, and log file was created.
In my case, log4j.properties is located in the root of class path.

i.e.)

classes/log4j.properties 
classes/com/idm/Test/log4jExample

please, check the location of log4j.properties.

Comment: @upuant where I have to place `log4j.properties` file on my Java Project?

Comment: Should I placed my `log4j.properties` file inside `src`?

Comment: @user3441151 Probably yes - to solve your current issue - , but what you really should do is to try to understand how log4j loads configuration and what it means to have something on the classpath root. You even should not place your log4j configuration into your application instead it should be "external".

Comment: If you have java project using Eclipse, please check the java build path.(click your project and check the menu : Build Path-Configure Build Path-Source Tab-Default output folder). Please place the log4j.properties file on the Default output folder root)~

Answer (score -1):

You should put log4j.properties in resource folder (source/main/resource), i think it will work correctly.
In case your project is java project (not maven project) i think you should change your code:
package com.idm.Test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class log4jExample {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    **PropertyConfigurator.configure("yourPath/log4j.properties");**
    log.info("Hello this is a debug message 1");
    log.info("Hello this is a debug message 2");
    log.info("Hello this is a debug message 3");
}
```

}

Comment: You assume that the OP uses a Maven project structure  - but this is wrong. He/She uses a Eclipse Java project.

Comment: you should not hard code the location of a configuration file in the code; instead specify the location via configuration (log4j provides this with the `log4j.configuration` system property)

Comment: yep, may be you're correct, because i don't know the way to work with log4j.configuration